# How to add data to a C# DataTable

Tags: c#, import, datatable, datarow

I thought this would be fairly easy yet here I am...  I am trying to simply add a new row to an existing  `DataTable` but the table won't take my row...

```
Debug.Print("My Achv Count Before: {0}", Manager.achievementsMine.Rows.Count);
DataRow newRow = Manager.achievementsMine.NewRow();
newRow.SetField<int>("CT_Q", count);
newRow.SetField<DateTime>("CMPL_D", DateTime.Now);
newRow.SetField<string>("USER_LAN_I", Manager.userID);
newRow.SetField<string>("ACHV_I", ACHV_I);
Manager.achievementsMine.ImportRow(newRow);
Manager.achievementsMine.AcceptChanges();
Debug.Print("My Achv Count After: {0}", Manager.achievementsMine.Rows.Count);
```

Both of the before/after 'Debug.Print' lines are showing me a count of 44.  Why wouldn't the 'after' debug tell me 45 since I just imported a new row and told the `DataTable` to accept the changes?

EDIT:
I tried rewriting some of the `newRow` parts but no change:

```
Debug.Print("My Achv Count Before: {0}", Manager.achievementsMine.Rows.Count);
DataRow newRow = Manager.achievementsMine.NewRow();
newRow["CT_Q"] = count;
newRow["CMPL_D"] = DateTime.Now;
newRow["USER_LAN_I"] = Manager.userID;
newRow["ACHV_I"] = ACHV_I;
Manager.achievementsMine.ImportRow(newRow);
Manager.achievementsMine.AcceptChanges();
Debug.Print("My Achv Count After: {0}", Manager.achievementsMine.Rows.Count);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use `NewRow` you have to `Add` the `DataRow` later to the table:

```
DataRow newRow = Manager.achievementsMine.NewRow();
newRow.SetField<int>("CT_Q", count);
newRow.SetField<DateTime>("CMPL_D", DateTime.Now);
newRow.SetField<string>("USER_LAN_I", Manager.userID);
newRow.SetField<string>("ACHV_I", ACHV_I);
Manager.achievementsMine.Rows.Add(newRow);
```

Another approach is using `DataRowColection.Add`:

```
DataRow newRow = Manager.achievementsMine.Rows.Add();
// you don't need to add this row since it's already added.
```

**Note**: Don't call [`AcceptChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you want to insert the new row to the database later. `AcceptChanges` will change it's `RowState` to unchanged, hence a `DataAdapter` cannot detect that this row is new. The `DataAdapter` itself will call it at the end of `Update`.

Comment: Thanks!!  'Rows.Add' worked!  I can't believe I didn't think of that because I've been doing the exact same thing for dynamically created HTML tables in C# code-behind for years now:  Table.Rows.Add(TableRow)